# Group by multiple columns and calculate the average sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have the below dataframe :

```
Customer    Category    Month   Mon_exp
  1            A          1      200
  1            A          1      100
  1            A          2      150
  1            B          2      150
  1            B          3      300
  2            A          1      300
  2            A          1      200
  2            A          2      150
  2            B          2      150
  2            B          3      400
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Customer    Category    Month   Mon_exp Ave_Mon_exp
   1          A           1      200    300
   1          A           1      100    300
   1          A           2      150    300
   1          B           2      150    300
   1          B           3      300    300
   2          A           1      300    400
   2          A           1      200    400
   2          A           2      150    400
   2          B           2      150    400
   2          B           3      400    400
```

Explanation for the new column 'Ave_Mon_exp' :

1) For Each customer, sum the 'Mon_exp' and divide with the count of unique 'Month' value.

For eg. Customer - 1, Sum of 'Mon_exp' is 900 and count of unique 'Month' value is 3. Hence the Ave_Mon_exp is 300.

Can anyone help me to derive the new column 'Ave_Mon_exp' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],'Category':['A','A','A','B','B','A','A','A','B','B'], 'Month': [1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3], 'Mon_exp': [200, 100, 150, 150, 300,300,200,150,150,400]})

new_col = sample.groupby('Customer')['Mon_exp'].sum()/ sample.groupby('Customer')['Month'].nunique()
new_col.name = 'Customer'
sample = sample.join(new_col, on='Customer', rsuffix='_Ave_Mon_exp')

print(sample_df)
```

Comment: @Shirkant Shete, Thanks, but since my real dataset is huge i would prefer something without loop concept.

Comment: @Shirkant Shete, Thanks.